# Swift XCTAssertEqual() for Date values - how to set part accuracy?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, date

Inside my Unit Test for Dates
let day = StockMarketDay(year: 2022, month: 1, day: 4)

```
    let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()      // no timezone
    formatter.formatOptions = [.withFullDate]
    let targetDate = formatter.date(from: "2022-01-04")!
    let timeAccuracy = TimeInterval(60*60*24)
    let dateAccuracy = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeAccuracy)
    print("dateAccuracy - \(dateAccuracy)")
   // XCTAssertEqual(day!.date, targetDate, accuracy: dateAccuracy) // Error
    XCTAssertEqual(day!.date, targetDate, accuracy: timeAccuracy) // Error
```

I get error: No exact matches in call to global function 'XCTAssertEqual'

It appears that the generic AssertEqual function must have a matching Type (e.g. Date) for the Accuracy parameter.  But I don't seem to guess at creating a proper accuracy date to pass in.

Anyone know of a way to Unit Test Dates with a specified accuracy?

Answer (score 3):

It might be worth trying to use `TimeIntervals` instead of dates, so change the XCTAssertEqual to this:

```
XCTAssertEqual(day!.date.timeIntervalSince1970, targetDate.timeIntervalSince1970, accuracy: timeAccuracy)
```

Comment: Hmmm ok I will try. But I have to say - it feels like a hack.

Comment: Your hack WORKS!